# Can't download over MacPorts

Tags: macports, mysql, php

So I'm trying to install the PDO drivers for PHP via Macports. I am using `install php5-mysql`, but when I hit enter I get

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

Not sure what to do now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Macports all commands start with port - port is the origami you run - install here looks like a totally different program /usr/bin/install

So try

```
sudo port install php5-mysql
```

The sudo is required as you will install into /opt/local which you will not have permission to write to.